# How to address Google User Data Privacy Policy Issue?

Tags: google-play, privacy-policy

I keep getting this rejection from Google Store and while I've tried adding many different clauses to the privacy policy, the rejection never was fixed. If someone can help me out please that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your app is uploading the list of installed application so that needs to be disclosed in the Privacy Policy. In addition, a prominent disclosure / notice to get consent from users on your data collection is required.

Examples of prominent disclosures / notices:

[image: Screenshot from TermsFeed on Google Prominent Disclosure example 1]
[image: Screenshot from TermsFeed on Google Prominent Disclosure example 2]
[image: Screenshot from TermsFeed on Google Prominent Disclosure example 3]

Credits for screenshots: [TermsFeed](https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/google-prominent-disclosure-requirement/)